# Как сделать ForeignKey к этому же классу в peewee?

Tags: python, orm

```
class Comment(Model):
    parent = ForeignKeyField(Comment)
    content = CharField()
    owner = ForeignKeyField(User)
```

Ругается на то, что класса Comment нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо класса впишите 'self'

```
parent = ForeignKeyField('self', null=True)
```